# Unable to view files stored in SD card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am dabbling with Android File I/O currently.
I am able to successfully save a file in SD card and I can read/pull this file from DDMS->File explorer successfully but I am not able see the file when viewing from PC

The path of the saved file is /mnt/.... But I don't see this folder/path in SD card when viewing from my PC

Can any one why I am not able to see the file from PC ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK when you connect your Android device to PC only /mnt/sdcard mounted automatically. So you should save your file to /mnt/sdcard/... or somehow mount entire /mnt by yourself or use adb to push/pull files from/to device.

Comment: the file is in /mnt/sdcard/<...custom folder...>/